# SQL query for 4 dates

Tags: sql

Writing a query to select user_ids based on allocation date:

below are the parameters I am using.

1. allocation start date
2. allocation end date
3. from date
4. to date

The below query is failing to get a result

```
SELECT 
  DISTINCT user_id
FROM 
  table_name
WHERE
  from_date <= allocation_start_date 
  AND to_date>=allocation_end_date
```

example:

```
user_id    allocation start date       allocation end
1                2022-08-10               2022-10-10
2                2022-05-01               2022-06-30
3                2022-05-01               2022-09-10
4                2022-05-01               2022-05-11
```

if I give from date as `2022-05-01` and to date as `2022-07-30`

I should get user ids `2` and `4`.

please help, not able to figure out this.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: How are you doing the quoting?  Date fields have to be quoted like strings.  Otherwise, `2022-05-01` is just an integer expression with the value `2016`.  Show us your code.

Comment: Even better, illustrate you use case in a fiddle of your  choice. For example, http://sqlfiddle.com/

Comment: So you're looking for overlapping date ranges? `from >= start and to <= end`

Answer (score 0):

to improve the readability of your queries you should define the column name first then the value.

You query should look like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM test
WHERE start >= '2022-05-01'
AND end <= '2022-07-30'
```

Here a db fiddle with a working example: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/cSHwLXyFr25GQvBvra91sE/0

Here the table definition:

```
CREATE TABLE test (
  id INT,
  start DATE,
  end DATE
);

INSERT INTO test
    (id, start, end)
VALUES
    (1, '2022-08-10', '2022-10-10'),
    (2, '2022-05-01', '2022-06-30'),
    (3, '2022-05-01', '2022-09-10'),
    (4, '2022-05-01', '2022-05-11')
;
```